# Find the minimal polynomial $f$ of $√5+i$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

The candidate is $x^4-8x^2+36=0$ but we cant use Eisenstein here to prove irreducibility. What do we do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, i)/\mathbb{Q} $ is Galois of degree 4, and the stabilizer of $ \sqrt{5} + i $ in the Galois group is the trivial group, which means that $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5} + i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, i) $ so that $ \sqrt{5} + i $ has degree $ 4 $ over $ \mathbb{Q} $. This means that the polynomial you've found is irreducible, and it is indeed the minimal polynomial.

A more elementary argument can be given by noting that

$$ \frac{6}{\sqrt{5} + i} = \frac{6(\sqrt{5} - i)}{6} = \sqrt{5} - i $$

so that we have $ \sqrt{5} - i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5} + i) $, and by extension $ \sqrt{5}, i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5} + i) $. The rest of the argument proceeds similarly.

To find the minimal polynomial, the easiest way is to note that we have

$$ m_{\alpha}(x) = \prod_{\sigma} (x - \sigma(\alpha)) $$

for any element $ \alpha $ of the extension, where the product runs over distinct $ \mathbb{Q} $-conjugates. Using this formula, we have for $ \alpha = \sqrt{5} + i $:

$$ m_{\alpha}(x) = (x - (\sqrt{5} + i))(x + (\sqrt{5} + i))(x - (\sqrt{5} - i))(x + (\sqrt{5} - i)) = (x^2 - (\sqrt{5} + i)^2)(x^2 + (\sqrt{5} - i)^2) = x^4 - 8x^2 + 36 $$

Comment: you can add links to wiki, say what is the concept you are using for deducing $i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+i)$, those kind of things

Comment: your elementary argument is much more obvious, tks.

Comment: what I don't understand is how things get different when looking at $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and at the $\mathbb{Q}$ conjugates of $\sqrt[3]{2}$

Comment: yes but how do I see this immediately ? (compared to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+i)/ \mathbb{Q}$ ?) I can see that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is $x^3-2$ but here the minimal polynomial is what we are searching

Comment: I think you are using in your answer the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory for saying that if $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+i)$ is a strict subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},i)$ then  $\sqrt{5}+i$ will be fixed by one of the non-trivial automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},i)/\mathbb{Q}$, which is not. (and also assuming that if $K/L$ is a normal extension of degree $\ge 2$ then $Gal(K/L)$ is non-trivial )

Comment: You can see this easily using the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, but the full strength of it is not necessary, it is enough to note that it has 4 distinct $ \mathbb{Q} $-conjugates, and therefore the subfield generated by it has degree 4 over $ \mathbb{Q} $.

Answer (score 1):

My “easiest” way of finding the $\Bbb Q$-irreducible polynomial for $\alpha=\sqrt5+i$ is this:

Certainly the $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5\,)$-irreducible polynomial for $\alpha$ is $(X-\sqrt5\,)^2+1=X^2-2\sqrt5X+6$. And so $(X^2-2\sqrt5X+6)(X^2+2\sqrt5X+6)=X^4-8X^2+36$ has the following three properties. It is the *only* factorization of the polynomial you found  into monic $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5\,)$-irreducibles; it is a $\Bbb Q$-polynomial; it is therefore $\Bbb Q$-irreducible.